# moving individual 230 pdf files to already created folders

Tags: gae-python27

@nmnhI'm trying to move over 200 pdf files, each to separate folders that are already created and named 2018. The destination path for each is like- GFG-0777>>2018.   Each pdf has an unique GFG-0### name that matches the folders I already created that lead to the 2018 destination folders. Not sure how to iterate and get each pdf into the right folder.... :/

I've tried shutil.move which i think is best but have issues with paths I think.

```
import os
import shutil


srcDir = r'C:\Complete'
#print (srcDir)
dstDir = r'C:\Python27\end_dir'
dirList = os.listdir(srcDir)
for f in dirList:
    fp = [f for f in dirList if ".pdf" in f] #list comprehension to iterate task (flat for loop)
for file in fp:
    dst = (srcDir+"/"+file[:-4]+"/"+dstDir+"/"+"2018")
    shutil.move(os.path.join(srcDir, dst, dstDir))
```

error: shutil.move(os.path.join(srcDir, dst, dstDir))
TypeError: move() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dst'

Comment: What did you try and why did it not work? Can you post your code/trace?

But essentially you need to get a list of your pdf names. E. G. Os. Listdir() and loop through them given the name and path

Comment: Thanks for responding nmanh. I'll respond a bit later with details when get into work. Basically imported os and shutil.  Tried to os.path.join the dst and src directories. I also use a comprehension list for loop calling the os.listdir

Comment: You could just update your original answer, would be better because of formatting :)

Comment: @nmanh ok.. obviously new to this

Comment: @nmnh fixed format of code.

Comment: @nmanh.  Hey.  Yeah. I answered myself. see below. Thanks for assist!

Comment: If my answer helped you, it would be great if you can mark it to be {a/the} answer. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT you are calling 
`shutil.move(os.path.join(srcDir, dst, dstDir))`
without a `to`.
According to the documentation you need to have a `from` and `to` folder.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move

I guess your idea was to somehow create a string containing the `dst` and `src` :

`dst = (srcDir+"/"+file[:-4]+"/"+dstDir+"/"+"2018")`

What you actually want is something along this line:

```
dst_dir = dstDir+"/"+"2018"
src_dir = srcDir+"/"+file[:-4]
shutil.move(src_dir,dst_dir)
```

Above code is just for demonstration.
If this does not work you could `tree` or `ls -la` example a small part of your srcdir and dstdir and we could work something out.

Comment: Thanks!! Will try and let ya know.

Comment: @SJCC did you come up with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

@nmanh
I managed to work it out.  Thanks for calling out the issue to create string with src and dst. After removing the string, I tweaked a bit more but found I had too many "file" in code. I had to make two of them "file1" and add a comma in the shutil.move between src and dst.
Thanks again

```
import os
import shutil


srcDir = r'C:\Complete'
#print (srcDir)
dstDir = r'C:\Python27\end_dir'
dirList = os.listdir(srcDir)
for file in dirList:
    fp = [f for f in dirList if ".pdf" in f] #list comprehension to iterate task 
    (flat for loop)
for file in fp:
    if ' ' in file: #removing space in some of pdf names noticed during fp print
    file1 = file.split(' ')[0]# removing space continued
else:
    file1 = file[:-4]# removing .pdf
    final = dstDir+"\\"+file1+"\\2018"
    print (srcDir+"\\"+file1+" "+final)
shutil.move(srcDir+"\\"+file,final)
```